# Google Dataproc Cluster Properties

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm looking to get more details on if these properties are for the whole cluster\each node or a combination of the two. for ecample `spark:spark.executor.instances

2`, is this a property for the whole cluster or a specific node?

[image]

Comment: The properties are configured in every node of the cluster. You can find them in /etc/spark.

Answer (score 0):

As dagang says, the various Dataproc properties should be identically set on every node of the cluster. The main config files you can file on each cluster corresponding to `spark:/core:/distcp:/hdfs:/mapred:/yarn:` are (in addition to others for additional optional components):

```
/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf/distcp-default.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml
```

Other files can be found in similar directories.

Comment: Is there a way to sync, say hbase-site.xml , across all the worker nodes in hbase enabled dataproc cluster, without having to manually copy one by one?